# Coercing a date object into a POSIXct object

Tags: r, date, posixct

When converting a date object to a POSIXct object, I expected the hours to be zero.
Turns out the hours are either 1 or 2, depending on summer/winter time.
eg:

```
oct.days <- (as.Date("2018-10-26")+0:5)
as.POSIXct(oct.days)
```

> [1] "2018-10-26 02:00:00 CEST" "2018-10-27 02:00:00 CEST" "2018-10-28 02:00:00 CEST"
>   [4] "2018-10-29 01:00:00 CET"  "2018-10-30 01:00:00 CET"  "2018-10-31 01:00:00 CET"

(I'm in Germany, winter time was implemented on Oct 28th at 3 am.)

Rounding it down fixed the issue
`round(as.POSIXct(oct.days),"days")`

but I wonder **for what reason the date object contains extra hours**?

tks!

Comment: Your times are midnight for the UTC time zone, because you're in Germany they're _displayed_ as 1/2 hours ahead.

Comment: Thanks @Hong Ooi, I tried specifying the timezone to "Europe/Berlin" but I always get the same output. I'm confused, shouldn't I get 00:00:00 times with this?
 
oct.days <- (as.Date("2018-10-26",tz="Europe/Berlin")+0:5)
as.POSIXct(oct.days)

Comment: `as.POSIXct(as.POSIXlt(oct.days, tz = "Europe/Berlin"), tz = "Europe/Berlin")` or use `tz = "GMT"` if you prefer to avoid the DST mess.